# MobileFirst 7.1 and Attribute Store over Extreme Scale

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, websphere-extreme-scale

I try to configure MFP Server 7.1 with Attribute Store over Extreme Scale.

MFP 7.1/Liberty 8.5.5.6/WXS 8.6/JSDK 1.8

Without specific zmfp.attrStore.*` properties the MFP Server works fine. If i add the following properties, i have the following error and no runtime available in the console.

The properties:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/mfp.session.independent" value='"true"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/mfp.attrStore.type" value='"eXtremeScale"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/mfp.attrStore.xs.endpoint" value='"192.168.1.41:2809"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/mfp.attrStore.xs.username" value='"xcadmin"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/mfp.attrStore.xs.password" value='"*******"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/mfp.attrStore.xs.gridname" value='"MFPGrid"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/mfp.attrStore.xs.mapname" value='"MFPGrid.NCI"'/>
```

The error:

> Impossible to establish a REST connection to:
>   service:jmx:rest://localhost:7443/IBMJMXConnectorREST

If i remove the properties `mfp.attrStore.*` the MFP Server works fine again.

logs files, server.xml, jvm.options available here: https://ibm.app.box.com/attrstore

Answer (score 0):

There is a defect in eXtreme scale that breaks totally the Liberty SSL configuration but there is a workaround as documented in https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_stateless_att_store_XS.html.

You have done the right workaround configuration but unfortunately something is missing in the workaround explanation : it works only with the IBM JDK and not at all with the Oracle JDK. So you must use the IBM JDK, preferably 1.7 (not sure 1.8 works well with eXtreme Scale).